# How to get superview's frame after rotation?

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation

I wanna get superview's frame after rotation. In my custom view, I listen to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                  selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:)
                      name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                    object:nil];
```

and then:

```
- (void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"superview: %@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.superview.frame]);
}
```

But it's the frame before rotation. The superview's frame hasn't rotated yet. If I get superview's frame after some delay, it's correct.

What's the proper way to get the superview's frame after rotation?

Comment: i think you should use – didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method of the UIViewController.

Comment: I add this custom view directly to some other view.

Comment: you can use rootViewController in app delegate for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you get the notification before the superview have done lay outing , basically you can use the notification to set a flag for example, `BOOL didRotate;` and then use this flag in
 `- (void)layoutSubviews` method (you override this method inside your view), this method will be called right after the rotation and the superview have changed its frame.

Comment: Well, instead of use a flag, I call `setNeedsLayout` in notification action. It works. I'm not sure whether it is the best practice.

Comment: The frame will be changed only after the call to setNeedsLayout. But that want guaranty that the frame will be changed according to rotation. do you get the correct frame ?

Comment: Yes, in the `- (void)layoutSubviews`, I get the correct frame.

Comment: The flag is to make sure you make your work only for rotation, because layoutSubviews can be called many times, at least twice after rotation or when you make animation on the superview. (don't forget to change the flag to NO in layoutSubviews) @smilingpoplar